# Создание проекта Google Maps Activity

Tags: android, android-studio, карты

Как сейчас создать проект Maps Activity? Раньше можно было создать проект на основе GM. А как это сделать сейчас?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Сам столкнулся с таким же вопросом, ответ нашел на youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4UG2T-yd46Q

Comment: [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Благодарю за комментарий и за проявленное внимание.

Отвечая на ваш комментарий, хочется отметить, что:
1) представление о содержимом содержится, как ни странно, в названии вопроса, к которому была дана ссылка.
2) цитировать самую необходимую информацию имеет смысл, когда это будет целесообразно, здесь же имеем видео на 18 минут, вся информация в видео - самая необходимая.
3) вижу что вы проголосовали за удаление моего ответа, однако мой ответ на момент написания - единственный. И это лучше, чем ничего. Если у вас есть желание ответить на этот вопрос подробно и с повествованием - делайте)